# Yafaray: Shadow-catcher

Tags: rendering, materials, light, external-applications, shadows

I have tracked footage in blender and placed a tank in the scene.  To get more realistic results, I switched over to Yafaray v3 render after setting up the tracking scene.

It seems that Yafaray can't use render layers, which breaks the node setup in blender.  How can I have the plane under the tank receive shadows but be transparent everywhere else, the way it occurs in blender internal and cycles?

Thanks,
Brody

Comment: This sounds more like a Yafaray problem than a Blender problem...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do this with the current YafaRay v3 versions. You can use the "Mask Object Index" render pass, for example, using the mask render pass that includes the shadows in the mask.

For example:
[image]
[image]

I have uploaded the example scene here: [cornellbox-yafaray-shadow-mask.blend.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJm3oFa7bxBcms2VzlucUpkd1k)

I hope this helps. Best regards!!